# After the fork, can I send my BTC out of Binance when it has not yet implemented the B2x wallet?

Tags: blockchain, segwit2x

Binance has committed to support the B2x fork.

Before the B2x fork, I sent my BTC to Binance to wait for the fork. A day after the fork and after it has crossed the block, can I send the BTC from Binance back to my Trezor now after the fork without waiting for Binance to implement the B2x fork?

Or can I sell my BTC now after the fork? Must I wait for Binance to implement the B2x fork before doing anything? Will I lose my B2x if I sell my BTC now?

Comment: B2X was cancelled in november 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Binance has told me that they taken a snapshot of all btc balances on their exchange. They are studying the issue and will make decision on whether to support B2x in the future.

But for some reason the tech help also told me to hold mt btc in the account until a decision is made